# Spectral theorem for diagonal matrix in different inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, orthogonality

I learned a special case of the spectral theorem for finite dimensional inner product space. As I understand it states that a real matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable with real eigenvalues iff it equal its hermitian adjoint. However when I try to apply it to diagonal matrices, I think I have a problem. If I work with the regular inner product ($\langle u,v\rangle \to u^tv)$ then I see how this works out ($A^* = A^t = A$), but if I work in a more general inner product space: $\langle u,v\rangle = (Bu)^t(Bv)$ where $B$ is an invertiable matrix, then the hermitian adjoint of a matrix $A$ becomes $A^* = (B^tB)^{-1}A^t(B^tB)$, and this may not commute with $A$, if $A$ is some general diagonal matrix, for example let's define $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. However we still have that for the identity matrix: $I^* = I$ so a diagonal matrix, is still orthogonally diagonalizable. How this doesn't contradict the spectral theorem?

Comment: Please clarify the issue, it's not clear what is going wrong for you

Comment: the matrix $A$ I defined is orthogonally diagonalizable, but it does not equal to its hermitian adjoint with the inner product I defined using the matrix $B$. How does this not contradict the spectral theorem?

Comment: Ofek, how do you prove your $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable? Remember that being "orthogonal" depends on the inner product

Comment: The matrix $A$ is diagonal and the identity matrix $I$ always equals its hermitian adjoint and is its own inverse.

Comment: I'm not really sure of the confusion here. The identity operator has only one eigenspace, corresponding to $1$, so it fulfills both premises and conclusions of the theorem. And no, the new adjoint may not commute with $A$; adjoints only commute if the matrix is normal. And while diagonal real matrices are normal (and indeed self-adjoint) when considering the usual inner product, they won't generally be self-adjoint or normal under other inner products.

Comment: My confusion is that from a naive reading of the spectral theorem, a diagonal real matrix must be self-adjoint, because it is orthogonally diagonalizable with real eigenvalues. And it is orthogonally diagonalizable, in every inner product space, because the identity matrix is always orthogonal.

Comment: Ofek, down here you can find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. Here is the real answer.

The true statement of the spectral theorem is that

> $A$ is selfadjoint iff there exists an **orthonormal basis** where $A$
> is real diagonal.

notice that having an orthonormal basis is way different than saying $A=QDQ^*$ where $D$ is real diagonal and $Q$ is orthogonal.

Instead, it means that $A=MDM^{-1}$ where the columns of $M$ are orthonormal, i.e. $<m_i,m_j>=\delta_{i,j}$.

In fact, the columns of the identity matrix $I$ do not form a orthonormal basis since $IB^TBI \ne I$ , or also said $<e_i,e_j> = (B^TB)_{i,j}\ne \delta_{i,j}$.

Hope that this makes it clear for you.

Comment: I think it does, thank you. I just have one small question for clarification. with the standard inner product, it is known that a matrix is orthogonal, iff its columns form an orthonormal basis (and it is easily proven staright from the definitions). So with that inner product, the statments: $A = QDQ^*$ where $Q$ is orthogonal (what I thought the spectral theroem means), and $A = QDQ^-1$ where the columns of $Q$ form an orthonormal basis (what it really means) are equivalent right?

Comment: the condition of being orthogonal is $Q^TB^TBQ=B^TB$, the condition of having orthonormal columns is $Q^TB^TBQ=I$, so when $B^TB=I$ they are eequivalent

Comment: And of course $B=I$ in the standard case. I think I get it now, thank you.